# How do you retrieve the new keys from an INSERT INTO SELECT FROM query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Is there a way to retrieve all the keys of the newly inserted records when using an INSERT INTO ... SELECT FROM query?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
DECLARE @MyVar TABLE ( ID int )

INSERT  INTO dbo.TargetTable
    OUTPUT  INSERTED.ID INTO @MyVar
SELECT * FROM    dbo.SourceTable

SELECT  * FROM    @MyVar
```

Comment: Can I have another column that captures the original Id too?

Comment: I think I got it, I'd just modify the table structure and then change the output line to something like this, right? OUTPUT  dbo.SourceTable.ID, INSERTED.ID INTO @MyVar

Comment: Yes, just add a column to @MyVar and one more INSERTED.Something

Answer (score 3):

Use [the OUTPUT clause](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx) to [capture them](http://www.sqlteam.com/article/using-the-output-clause-to-capture-identity-values-on-multi-row-inserts) (SQL Server 2005 and up).

Comment: Good to know. I don't have to use cursors anymore :)

Answer (score 0):

Some databases support the `INSERT INTO ... SELECT ... RETURNING ...` syntax. Since you are using TSQL, I believe the syntax for that is:

```
INSERT INTO table (fields...)
OUTPUT outputfields...
SELECT ...
```

There's a PDF on the issue: [Returning.pdf](http://www.decipherinfosys.com/Returning.pdf)