# Inserting records in database tables using "inheritance"

Tags: sql-server, database-design

I have a table whose primary key is also a foreign key to the primary key of another table (i.e. "inheritance" as simulated in a database).

```
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[BaseClass]    Script Date: 07/15/2011 18:17:27 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[BaseClass](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Title] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [Description] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_BaseClass] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

USE [TestConcepts]
GO

/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[DerivedTable]    Script Date: 07/15/2011 18:17:49 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[DerivedTable](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [SpecialProperty] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_DerivedTable] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[DerivedTable]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_DerivedTable_BaseClass] FOREIGN KEY([ID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[BaseClass] ([ID])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[DerivedTable] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_DerivedTable_BaseClass]
GO
```

What is the proper way to insert records in this situation? Obviously an insert doesn't return the PK of the inserted row (plus the child's table's PK is identity as well).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Nobody calls this "inheritance".  That's not what it is.  It's a relation, the R in RDBMS.
2. INSERTs *do* tell you the PK of the just-inserted row.  Look at @@SCOPE_IDENTITY on SQL Server.

Comment: First, you're right that it's just a relation but it IS a *simulation* of inheritance and many people DO use that term to refer to this construct. There's a reason I put quote marks around "inheritance". Second, SCOPE_IDENTITY will work perfectly. Thanks.

Comment: A couple links that mention "inheritance" in databases: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_Table_Inheritance, http://www.sqlteam.com/article/implementing-table-inheritance-in-sql-server

Comment: 'll grant you your interpretation, but in a pretty sizable career in this industry I've hardly ever seen it applied to these kinds of relationships unless the relationship between the tables was truly an inheritance relationship (which is not often).

Comment: In my case it specifically is an inheritance relationship. Perhaps if I'd posted my actual tables it would have been more obvious. ;) Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 4):

Here are a **[few examples](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user:196713%20subtype)** of this pattern.

The sub-type table should **not** have auto-increment ID, the ID matches the one in the super-type table.

The basic technique (using your example) looks something like

```
DECLARE @MY_ID integer;
INSERT INTO BaseTable(Title, Description)
    VALUES ('title_here', 'blah, blah');
SELECT @MY_ID = SCOPE_IDENTITY();

INSERT INTO DerivedTable(ID, SpecialProperty)
    VALUES (@MY_ID, newid()); -- the SpecialProperty is uniqueidentifier
```

One approach is to create a view, one for each sub-type table, or just one over all of them. Then create an `INSTEAD OF INSERT TRIGGER` on the view and use the technique inside the trigger.

You may also find **[this technique](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1863665/how-do-you-retrieve-the-new-keys-from-an-insert-into-select-from-query/1863705#1863705)** for capturing multiple inserted IDs useful too.

Answer (score 0):

The DERIVEDCLASS table *could* have an auto-incremented (identity) PK but if so there must be another column that is a foreign key reference back to BASETABLE:

```
          BASETABLE
          id int pk autoincrement
          baseattribute1
          baseattribute2
          etc etc


           DERIVEDTABLE
           id  int pk autoincrement
           **baseid**  foreign key references BASETABLE(id)
           extendedattribute1
           extendedattribute2
```

This would permit multiple derivations of each base entity.  Placing a unique index on DERIVEDTABLE.baseid or making baseid the PK would prevent this, if that is desired.

The following would instantiate the members of the base class and their derived instances and/or extended properties if any [which it is will depend on whether baseid has unique constraint in DerivedTable; if the latter it could be the PK in a one-to-one relationship with BaseTable, rather than a many-to-one]:

```
          select * from BASETABLE
          LEFT JOIN DERIVEDTABLE
          on BASETABLE.id = DERIVEDTABLE.baseid
```

Instances of the base class that have not been extended will have NULL in the extendedattribute columns.

To find only those entities that have been extended use an inner join:

```
         select * from DERIVEDTABLE
         inner join BASETABLE
         on DERIVEDTABLE.baseid = BASETABLE.id
```